# jQuery .GET or .POST don't work on IE by calling the file from a different domain

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, get

I m using AJAX to get a PHP file from another domain name.

In fact the domain where I have installed the jQuery function does not support the PHP send mail function, so I had to use an external web server to send the emails out.

This is what I have done with jQuery:

```
if(hasError == false) {

        var referenteVal = $("#referente").val();
        var cittaVal = $("#citta").val();
        var provinciaVal = $("#provincia").val();
        var offertaVal = $("#offerta").val();
            $.get("http://externaldomain.com/send_mail.php",
                { nome: emailToVal, email: emailFromVal, telefono: telefonoVal, referente: referenteVal, citta: cittaVal, provincia: provinciaVal, commento: messaggioVal, offerta: offertaVal},
                    function(data){
                    if(data=='errore') {
                        alert('ERRORE'); }
                        else{
                        alert('Grazie! Messaggio inviato. La ricontatteremo il prima possibile.');
                        $.fancybox.close();
                        }
                    }
                 );
```

Now this code works just fine in every browser but NOT in IE.

In fact in IE I get an Access Denied Error for my jQuery code!!

How do I fix it?

What is the problem?

Why IE is not allowing me to do a GET request to a different domain name??

Thanks!

Comment: Are you 100% sure this works in other browsers? It shouldn't. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Yes it works just fine in Firefox, safari and even in some IEs. But not in the one of my Client!!

Comment: Go into Internet Options -> Security Tab -> Custom Settings

Enable "Access data sources accross domains" under Miscellaneous

Comment: I am looking for something that does not require an action by the user....

Comment: ok, you might want to 'google' for XDomainRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make call to different domains you should use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set `crossDomain` to `true` and `dataType` to `jsonp` i think.